# Set “samesite=none” in aiohttp EncryptedCookieStorage

Tags: cookies, aiohttp

I create app  with code like

```
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp_session import setup
from aiohttp_session.cookie_storage import EncryptedCookieStorage

app = web.Application(
    middlewares=[
        api_auth,
    ],
)
setup(app, EncryptedCookieStorage(SECRET_KEY, httponly=False))
```

how can i set `samesite=none` for cookie storage ?

Answer (score 1):

I) need aiohttp>=3.7.0

II) use patched version of EncryptedCookieStorage

```
class PatchedEncryptedCookieStorage(EncryptedCookieStorage):
    def __init__(self, key, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(key, **kwargs)
        self._cookie_params["samesite"] = "none"

setup(app, PatchedEncryptedCookieStorage(SECRET_KEY, httponly=False))
```